# Jquery AJAX live output?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get some live output from an AJAX request.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET",   
     url: "test.php?delete=students",   
     async: true,
     success : function(data) {
         console.log(data)
     }
    });
```

When triggered by a link on my web page a spinning animation is shown to show that something is happening. I'd also like to show in a `div` the output from test.php as it is running.

test.php has a simple loop which loops through all students and deletes them, it then `echo "$student removed";`

When run from the command line the removals are shown, when run via AJAX I only get the animation not the output.

I'm not sure how to get that, I've tried a couple of plugin's with out much success. I've also tried to use `XMLHttpRequest` and `responseText` but i'm not sure how to use this correctly.

Ideally I'd like each removal to be shown in a `#status` div.

Can any one advise how to do this ?

**UPDATE**

```
 progress : function(data) {
    console.log(data);
 },
```

I've added the above and move I get some output in the console.
`ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 44, total: 0, type: "progress"…}`

Expanding that I can see the responsetext which contains the data I'm after.
How do I get that so I can append it to a `div` ?

Comment: If i'm correct, `success` in AJAX calls the callback only after php closes the HTTP connection, I myself am confused so hoping for more responses.

Comment: Hi. `success` does return correctly, I'm trying to get the output as it's happening. Just about to update my original post

Comment: what i mean to say is, you can't stream the progress of tets.php, the browser won't read any of it until, the php connection is closed

Comment: I can get some progress, I'm not sure how to get the the text.

Comment: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/, use this. Should help. Also, I'm sorry. I think I have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using Server-sent events for it: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#server-sent-events

Client code will be simple:

```
var sse = new EventSource('test.php?delete=students');
sse.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  console.log(e.data);
}, false);
```

In your test.php code will look something like the following:

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

for ($i = 0; $i < ob_get_level(); $i++) {//for each open buffer
  ob_end_flush();//close it
}

ob_implicit_flush(1);//turn implicit flush on

//now goes what you called "loops through all students and deletes them"
while(1) {
  /*here you post your code that deletes your student*/
  $data = "$student removed";//message to send to client confirming deleting of particular student
  echo "data: ".$data . PHP_EOL;//here you send data to client, it will receive it and handle inside 'message' event handler
  echo PHP_EOL;//need this just to fulfill the SSE standard
  sleep(1);//use if need to insert pause between sending new portion of data (better use it to keep your browser safe from too much of messages per second)
}
```

Don't forget to break your loop after finishing deleting students=)

Comment: Hi thanks for this I will try it later today - will there be any issue with time outs ? if test.php takes x mins to complete will that cause any issues ? it could be deleting or updating 100,000 entries.

Comment: If connection drops, EventSource tries to reopen it automatically. So you'll need only to ensure that your server-side logic stops executing if remote client disconnects (check your 'ignore_user_abort' is set to 'off' in php.ini if there will be any problems with it) and continues from last operation after connection has been reopened. You can also use 'error' event handler on client side to notify client if something goes wrong. Check link in my answer to get more information about it.

Comment: Sorry only just managed to get back to this.. I get the error `EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.`

Comment: ensure you've sent headers properly

Comment: I've come back to this and it is passing the message from the backend script to the browsers console. However it keeps sending event when the code is complete. My backend script is doing `echo "data: REMOVED" . PHP_EOL; echo PHP_EOL; exit;` yest the console with show REMOVED has been received multiple times.  How do I stop that ?